# Hisense All-in-one Point Of Sale Printing problem

Tags: printing, display

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Hisense All-in-one Point Of Sale (HK716) manufactured by Qingdao Hisense Intelligent Commercial System Co., Ltd.

I purchased this PC through reseller. The PC was loaded with Windows 10. 
I decided to use Ubuntu

The problems which I have is I am not able to configure printer(Model: POS802 3" THERMAL PRINTER)  correctly moreover the second display cannot mirror with my builtin display for customer display. I have installed Odoo 13 POS software (Running on webrowser)and it is running perfectly. The problem lies with printing receipts after each sale –

Please advise how to resolve this issue

Comment: You'd need to have Point of Sale software installed, and configure it to use the printer. There's many POS systems, so cannot recommend a particular one.

Comment: I have installed odoo 13 and it is running perfectly. the problem lies with printing receipts after each sale

Comment: **CLOSE VOTERS**:  I see there's already two votes under "Needs detail or clarity". Can you please leave comments at least stating what details and clarity are needed ?  If you aren't familiar with POS systems and thermal printers, please refrain from voting on this question